# Want to pass a predicate to a method to get a Dictionary result

Tags: c#, dictionary

Basically i want to pass a predicate to a method which result a dictionnary result with Entity associated to a specific Id. But this doesn't seem to work..

```
public Dictionary<int, Room> GetRooms(Func<KeyValuePair<int, Room>, bool> predicate)
{
      return _rooms.Where(predicate).ToDictionary<Room, int>(x => x.Key);
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return statement should return `Dictionary<int,Room>`, not `Dictionary<Room,int>`. You also need to select the value, otherwise you get a `Dictionary<int,KeyValuePair<int,Room>>`:

```
return _rooms.Where(predicate).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```